# Spring Batch, JdbcPagingItemReader - alias doesn't map to the Mapper bean attribute

Tags: java, spring-batch

```
select item_num 
      ,T1.sht_name as "\"T1.sht_name\"  (...alias set in Spring Batch Java code)
      ,T2.lct_num
 from ITEM T1 INNER JOIN LOCATION T2
   on T1.sht_name = T2.sht_name
 where T1.code = 1
orderby item_num, T1.sht_name, T2.lct_num
```

> I have set the above query in the provider.setSelectClause,
> provider.setFromClause and provider.setWhereClause respectively.   I
> am setting the sort keys as:

```
sortConfiguration.put("item_num", Order.ASCENDING);
sortConfiguration.put("T1.sht_name", Order.ASCENDING);
sortConfiguration.put("lct_num", Order.ASCENDING);
```

Mapper bean is :

```
public class ItemBean implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private int itemNum;
            private String shtName;
            private Integer lctNum;
        }
```

reader bean:

```
    @Bean
      public JdbcPagingItemReader<ItemBean > testBatchReader() {
    
        JdbcPagingItemReader<ItemBean > reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(db2Config.db2DataSource());
        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider());
        reader.setPageSize(chunkSize);
        reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(ItemBean.class));
    
        return reader;
      }
```

> However, when I execute the Batch, null is obtained for *shtName*. That
> implies the fetched column is not getting mapped to the Mapper bean
> attribute *shtName*. Any help would be appreciated. (I am thinking to
> use **RepositoryItemReader** if this cannot be mapped but there too I
> am not sure how to map the sort keys for the dependent table
> (LOCATION) column (*T2.sht_name)*).

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64928337/spring-batch-jdbcpagingitemreader-doesnt-obtain-page-1-onwards/71726384#71726384) question. check my answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/71726384/3689438](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71726384/3689438)