# Spring batch: JdbcPagingItemReader doesn't obtain page 1 onwards

Tags: jdbc, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, mssql-jdbc

Here my reader:

```java
@Bean
public ItemReader<Unitat> itemReader(PagingQueryProvider queryProvider) {
    return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<Unitat>()
        .name("creditReader")
        .dataSource(this.dataSource)
        .queryProvider(queryProvider)
        .rowMapper(this.unitatMapper)
        .pageSize(2)
        .build();
}

@Bean
    public SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean queryProvider() {
        SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean provider = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();

        provider.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        provider.setSelectClause("SELECT im_notext1.nt1_id");
        provider.setFromClause("FROM im_notext1 LEFT OUTER JOIN im_notext2 ON im_notext1.nt1_id = im_notext2.nt1_id");
        provider.setSortKey("nt1_id");

        return provider;
    }
```

Formatted query is:

```sql
SELECT
  TOP 2 im_notext1.nt1_id
FROM
  im_notext1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN im_notext2 ON im_notext1.nt1_id = im_notext2.nt1_id
ORDER BY
  nt1_id ASC
```

I know, it seems a dummy query. Only for simplifying context.

Shortly, `PagingQueryProvider` is engaged to generate "paged queries" like:

Page 0:

```sql
SELECT
  TOP 2 im_notext1.nt1_id
FROM
  im_notext1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN im_notext2 ON im_notext1.nt1_id = im_notext2.nt1_id
ORDER BY
  nt1_id ASC
```

Page 1:

```sql
SELECT
  TOP 2 im_notext1.nt1_id
FROM
  im_notext1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN im_notext2 ON im_notext1.nt1_id = im_notext2.nt1_id
WHERE
  ((nt1_id > ?))
ORDER BY
  nt1_id ASC
```

I've activated logs:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.batch.item.database=debug
```

I'm getting this error message:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ambiguous column name 'nt1_id'.

Really, `nt1_id` column is on both `im_notext1` and `im_notext2` tables (joined on `from` clause).

Logs:

```
Reading page 0
SQL used for reading first page: [SELECT TOP 2 im_notext1.nt1_id FROM im_notext1 LEFT OUTER JOIN im_notext2 ON im_notext1.nt1_id = im_notext2.nt1_id ORDER BY nt1_id ASC]
Reading page 1
SQL used for reading remaining pages: [SELECT TOP 2 im_notext1.nt1_id FROM im_notext1 LEFT OUTER JOIN im_notext2 ON im_notext1.nt1_id = im_notext2.nt1_id WHERE ((nt1_id > ?)) ORDER BY nt1_id ASC]
Using parameterList:[244029]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use the actual column name (`im_notext1.nt1_id`) in the `where` clause. You can't use the alias you defined in the `select` clause in the `where`, because logically, the `where` clause is evaluated before the `select` clause, so the alias 'doesn't exist' from the perspective of the `where`. However, as the generated query doesn't match your code, I'm going to guess something extra might be in play inside Spring JDBC. I don't have the time to investigate that, so I deleted my earlier answer and posted this comment.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've edited post. Could you take a look please? I think the problem is on other side.

Comment: I guess the workaround is to nest your query in a table expression in the from (i.e. select * from (<your actual select>), so that you have unambiguous column names. I don't use Spring JDBC a lot, so I can't really help with this without investing a lot of time I don't have right now.

Comment: Is this related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1124?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue using `JdbcPagingItemReader` with sql having column name alias

resolve it by nesting  query in a table expression in the from (i.e. select * from (), so that I have unambiguous column names.

Before

```
SELECT
    C.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY_ID 
  , C.PRICE
FROM
    MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_1        A
    JOIN MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_2   B ON B.STORAGE_ID = A.STORAGE_ID
    JOIN MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_3   C ON C.CATEGORY_ID = B.CATEGORY_ID
ORDER BY C.CATEGORY_ID asc
```

After

```
SELECT CATEGORY_ID from (
SELECT
    C.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY_ID 
  , C.PRICE
FROM
    MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_1        A
    JOIN MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_2   B ON B.STORAGE_ID = A.STORAGE_ID
    JOIN MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_3   C ON C.CATEGORY_ID = B.CATEGORY_ID
    )
ORDER BY CATEGORY_ID asc
```